# Vite, Elastic UI: Failing to dynamically import icons for EuiIcon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, elasticui

https://github.com/rorymcd98/spot-the-image-gen

Here's my repo. To install simply do:

yarn install

yarn dev

The issue that I'm having is with Elastic UI's `EuiIcon` in the `./src/components/Counters.tsx`. I'm trying to import `shard` and `bullseye` type icons.

Problem: As you can see, in the current version they are not rendering. In the `dev` server I'm getting an error:

`caught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/assets/bullseye?import`

I've tried quite a few things, but based on the documentation I can't tell where I'm going wrong. I have tried creating a `public/assets/{name}.svg` file for each but this didn't appear to work.

Could someone take a brief look at my repo and see where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: did you end up getting this working?

Comment: I ended up going with a variant of your solution I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Did some quick research on this. Found the solution in the wiki.

Just import the icons and pass them to the function `appendIconComponentCache`.

```js
import { appendIconComponentCache } from '@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/icon';

import { icon as EuiIconArrowDown } from '@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/assets/arrow_down';
import { icon as EuiIconArrowLeft } from '@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/assets/arrow_left';

// One or more icons are passed in as an object of iconKey (string): IconComponent
appendIconComponentCache({
  arrowDown: EuiIconArrowDown,
  arrowLeft: EuiIconArrowLeft,
});
```

https://github.com/elastic/eui/tree/main/wiki/consuming-eui#failing-icon-imports

Answer (score 0):

Since [@kurupt_89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301423/19600716) is for JavaScript, I post the following as a complement for TypeScript.

1. Import the whole set of icons using [this file](https://gist.github.com/Alecton4/66c9eee74ad94d463523a8dfb65f6a01).
2. Or only import the icons you want by adding a file containing codes similar to the following to your project:

   ```js
   import { ICON_TYPES } from "@elastic/eui";
   import { appendIconComponentCache } from "@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/icon";

   // Suppose you want to use the "exit" icon
   import { icon as exit } from "@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/assets/exit";

   type IconComponentNameType = (typeof ICON_TYPES)[0];
   type IconComponentCacheType = Partial<Record<IconComponentNameType, unknown>>;

   const cachedIcons: IconComponentCacheType = {
     exit,
   };

   appendIconComponentCache(cachedIcons);
   ```
3. Create a `global.d.ts` file containing the following code to suppress TypeScript's error:

   ```js
   declare module "@elastic/eui/es/components/icon/*";
   ```

For more information you can check [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/eui/issues/5463).